# How to upload firmware to my board

Tags: esp32, bootloader, uploading, flash

I am using platformio to develop ESP32-S2-MINI-2. I want to send it to factory to test it and they are not using platformio to upload. Do they also need to flash bootloader.bin and partition.bin? in which address? is firmware.bin to 0x0?

They are getting error of invalid header: 0xefffffff while flashing it.